# How to automatically detect NxM relationships in an Oracle database?

Tags: python, mongodb, oracle

Im creating a python script that, given an Oracle database, create another script with commands to create the same database, with the same data, but in MongoDB.

For N:1 relationships is trivial, but for NxM relationships Im struggling trying to automatically detect them to determine the order of the inserts. Is there any way to do it automatically?

Edit:

For example: in case of the relationship between person and groups, a person can be in N groups and a group can held M persons, thats an MxN relationship.
In SQL, we should have 3 different tables to represent this relationship, as shown in the picture:
[image]

To convert it to MongoDB, I will create using cross references,  like show in the picture:
[image]

To do that, I will create the inserts with commands like:

```
var doc = db.groups.findOne(name: “IT course”);
db.person.insert(name: “Chris”, courses:[doc]);
```

Comment: Please define "NxM" and provide an example, and explain what kind of inserts you're doing and why they have to be done in a particular order.

Comment: I just edited the main text with some context

Comment: You can query the `all_constraints` and `all_cons_columns` view in the data dictionary to find out which foreign keys are referencing a certain table (for example Person_Group is referencing Group) and then pull all `person_id` for that Group. Or create the persons without groups (and the groups without persons) first and then add them later in one go based on the Person_Group table (but my knowledge of MongoDB is not sufficient to know if that's possible).

Comment: A "many-to-many" requires a bridge table (here, `person_group`) which should have FKs pointing to each of two other tables. Any table with FKs to more than one table technically creates a many-to-many condition between the parent tables it references. But of course not every such relationship is meaningful. It'll be difficult to do that programmatically. Even if you are okay with all the possible many-to-manys, you would still have to assume that all relationships are defined with foreign key constraints. In many databases the logical relationships (or some) aren't enforced as they should be.